# MySQL communications link failure on specific SQL with EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

EclipseLink 2.5.1, Tomcat 7, MySQL JDBC driver 5.1.31. I have a specific SELECT statement that consistently produces comm link failure when executed by my webapp (running exactly the same SELECT in mysql client works just fine, and results come back in about 800ms). I have fiddled around with timeout settings on MySQL, no difference.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 912 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 901 milliseconds ago.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ...

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 912 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 901 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor523.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3567)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
```

The MySQL server is local, here is JNDI:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/my-mysql"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          maxActive="100"
          minIdle="10"
          maxWait="10000"
          initialSize="10"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          logAbandoned="true"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          username="my"
          password="my"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;socketTimeout=900&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true"/>
```

and here is persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/my-mysql</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.initial" value="16" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.min" value="64" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.max" value="128" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is it just this one query or others in the application?  Also note that the eclipselink.connection-pool settings should not be used if you are using a datasource - they are used to configure an EclipseLink controlled connection pool.

Comment: Intermittently other queries fail as well. Another funny thing is that exactly the same WAR deployed on testing server executes the very same SQL just fine. I had the same issue intermittently before connection-pool settings were added... I'll try to remove them anyway and see what happens

Comment: You have parameters set on the JDBC connection used, such as socketTimeout=900 which might be contributing to the problem.  The connection's socket will timeout after 900 milli seconds, which a query that is expected to take 800ms is pushing very close to.  You might want to remove this timeout and test again.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, will try! For some reason I thought the timeout is set in seconds, not ms

Comment: I believe you were spot on with socketTimeout setting. Please submit answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the socketTimeout=900 value is not enough time for a query expected to take 800ms in the test environment.  This value causes the socket itself to timeout before the query can return.  Changing this value to give the query the time it needs to complete when the system and network are under load will resolve the issue.